# Compare floats in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, floating-point

I have 6 InputFields in my scene. Their content type is decimal.

I fetch values from these input fields and check if their sum is equal to 100.02. I enter 16.67 in all of them.

```
    float fireP   =  float.Parse(firePercentage.text);
    float waterP  =  float.Parse(waterPercentage.text);
    float lightP  =  float.Parse(lightPercentage.text);
    float nightP  =  float.Parse(nightPercentage.text);
    float natureP =  float.Parse(naturePercentage.text);
    float healthP =  float.Parse(healthPercentage.text);

    float total = fireP + waterP + lightP + nightP + natureP + healthP;

   if (total == 100.02f)
   {
     Debug.Log("It's equal");
   }
   else
   {
     Debug.Log(" Not equal. Your sum is = " + total);
   }
```

I am getting " Not equal. Your sum is = 100.02" in my console log.
Anyways has any idea why this might be happening ?

Comment: What is the value of total in the debug mode?

Comment: @fubo double is enough. The point is though that floating point numbers should *not* be compared for equality

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx?printable=true

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič it was 100.02... 
But after more research I found out Debug.log shows rounded off values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nearest `float` to `16.67` is `16.6700000762939453125`.

The nearest `float` to `100.02` is `100.01999664306640625`

Adding the former to itself 5 times is not *exactly* equal to the latter, so they will not compare equal.

In this *particular* case, comparing with a *tolerance* in the order of 1e-6 is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 25):

You indeed have a floating point issue.

In unity you can and should use [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html), it's a utility function they built exactly for this purpose

**Try this**

```
if (Mathf.Approximately(total, 100.02f))
{
    Debug.Log("It's equal");
}
else
{
   Debug.Log(" Not equal. Your sum is = " + total);
}
```

Additionally, as a side note, you should work with Decimals if you plan on doing any calculations where having the EXACT number is of critical importance. It is a slightly bigger data structure, and thus slower, but it is designed not to have floating point issues. (or accurate to 10^28 at least)

For 99.99% of cases floats and doubles are enough, given that you compare them properly.

A more in-depth explanation can be found here : [Difference between decimal float and double in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

Comment: This works right. I had already tried this. But I wanted to know why exactly does this happen. Thanks for the reply, it will help everyone stuck on this issue but @Snoop Dog 's answer is why it is really happening.