# Why when calculating distance moving object passed the result i'm getting is very high?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At Start function

```
private void Start()
    {
        spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MySphere");
        lastPosition = spheres [0].transform.position;
    }
```

lastPosition is Vector3 type

Then in the Update function:

```
private void Update()
    {
        UpdateSpheres();
        MoveShips ();
    }
```

And in the MoveShips now i have only one ship for the test:

```
private void MoveShips()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in spheres[0].transform)
        {
            child.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

            distanceTravelled += Vector3.Distance (child.transform.position, lastPosition);
            if (distanceTravelled == 30) 
            {
                child.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f,180f,0f));
            }
        }
    }
```

But when running the game it's never get into the Rotate line.
I used a break point.

Comment: Did you debug and check that `distanceTravelled` ever gets to `30`? I assume you are looking for ` if (distanceTravelled >= 30)`

Comment: As said in another comment, you need to compare with >=, You are comparing floats, the distance will (very likely) never be EXACTLY 30. See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898301/if-statement-not-working-checking-float-value/39898363#39898363