# position check between object and point. Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
    if (((float) (Math.Round(gameObject.transform.position.x, 1))) == ((float) (Math.Round(array[i].x, 1))) && (((float) (Math.Round(gameObject.transform.position.y, 1))) ==  (float) (Math.Round(array[i].y, 1))))
```

Hello! I am using C#, and the array is filled with vector positions. I am trying to see when an object gets to a certain position. This never triggers. Do you have any other tips how to do this?

Comment: It wont work because of precision. You can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874627/floating-point-comparison-functions-for-c-sharp) for how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing `float` values directly ... **never** do that. It leads to a problem with the [floating point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). `float` values are internally actually stored in increments of an [Epsilon](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html).

see e.g. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39898362/7111561)

> The nearest `float` to `16.67` is `16.6700000762939453125`
>
> The nearest `float` to `100.02` is `100.01999664306640625`

or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net) for a broader explenation.

---

Use [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html)!

Preferably with a certain threshold distance. There is an example that looks exactly like what you want to do in [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) (in JavaScript but the difference to c# in this case is minimal)

```c#
public float threshold = 0.1f;

//...

if(Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, array[i]) <= threshold)
{
    ....
}
```

Adjust `threshold` so it has a value that is bigger than what the object can possibly move between two frames.

Or together with [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)

```c#
if(Math.Approximately(Vector3.Distance(object.transform.position, array[i]), 0.0f))
{
    ....
}
```

if your threshold is smaller than `0.00001` than you could also use

```c#
if(object.transform.position == array[i])
{
    ....
}
```

since [`==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) uses `<= 0.00001` for equality.

**But note:** In the most cases the last two options will also fail because the opts for a moving GameObject to match an exact 3D position are almost 0 unless you set fixed values somewhere.

---

`Vector3.Distance` also works with a `Vector2` as parameter since an implicit typecast to `Vector3` exists.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why my program crashes when i i wrap that if statement with: while(x==1) { if statement with x=0;

Comment: most probably because you don't ever move your object insdie the while loop or it simply never matches the position for any other reason? Do your check only in `Update` without a `while` .. `Update` si called every frame that should be enough. Or checkout [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) (just noticed there is actually exactly the example I provided above using `Distance` ;) )